# in C, a variable doesn't retain the value i assign it and goes back to 0

Tags: c, game-engine, allegro

I am writing a simple game engine in C and I have come across a very odd problem.

```
//SANJI
objs[1].animation = 1;
objs[1].pho.h = 52;
objs[1].pho.w = 25;
objs[1].pho.tmp_pos.x = 190;
objs[1].pho.tmp_pos.y = 40;
objs[1].pho.gravity = 1;
objs[1].hp = 10;

printf("%d\n", objs[1].hp);//outputs 0???????
```

It seems no matter what I do the variable (member) `hp` is refusing to accept the assignment and goes back to `0`. I tried searching with Google, but I am afraid I am unable to phrase this problem accurately.

EDIT:
this is the definition of the  OBJ struct:

```
struct OBJ{
//animation
char animation;//if true apply animation; experimetnal

MOVIE   sprites;
PHYSOBJ pho;

//OBJ_STATE state;
OBJ_STATE states[SEQ_MAX][ST_MAX];
int img;//number of image


int hp;

//control; AI or human
char control;//0 human, otherwise AI
};
```

Also there is no code between the printf and objs[1].hp = 10; i put the printf there for testing

Comment: `hp` and `objs[1].hp` are two different things. It would help to see a [mcve].

Comment: At a minimum, please post the code where you define the struct for "objs".  That would tell us how hp is defined, and how it relates to objs.  But a COMPLETE example would be best: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Need to see how you define "objs", and are you sure the "%d" is correct?

Comment: How much code is there between the assignment `objs[1].hp = 10;` and the `printf()`?  How big an array is `objs`?  How is the structure type defined?  Did you make sure there were no warnings from you compiler set to very fussy? It is almost certain that you've managed to find a way to invoke ['undefined behaviour'](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.4.3), which is bad news but not very hard to do.

Comment: do other variables have same behaviors?

Comment: This complete example: https://ideone.com/DqW1j1 works fine, so it would seem there's something in the code we can't see or replicate without assistance from you.

Comment: what is the definition of: `MOVIE` and `PHYSOBJ` and `OBJ_STATE` and what are the values of: `SEQ_MAX` and `ST_MAX`?

Comment: regarding:`objs[1].animation = 1;`  the field: `animation` is defined as a char, so assigning `1` to that field is an error.  I.E. a `char` is 8bits, but `1` is (in most systems) 32 bits with a content of `0x00000001`.  The implicit conversion feature of C will probably save you, but you should not depend on such assistance

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings. ( for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu17` ) Note: other compilers use different options to enable the same

Comment: please post the declaration of `objs[]`

Comment: @user3629249: `objs[1].animation = 1;` is just fine. Furthermore, C has no way to write a one-byte integer literal so you have to let the compiler do the int-to-char conversion..

Answer (score 2):

the following proposed code:

1. demonstrates (typically) how the function would be written
2. cleanly compiles
3. performs the desired functionalilty

and now the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct POS
{
    int x;
    int y;
};


struct PHO
{
    int h;
    int w;
    struct POS tmp_pos;
    int gravity;
};
typedef struct PHO PHYSOBJ;


struct OBJ
{
    //animation
    char animation;//if true apply animation; experimetnal

    //MOVIE   sprites;
    PHYSOBJ pho;

    //OBJ_STATE state;
    //OBJ_STATE states[SEQ_MAX][ST_MAX];
    int img;//number of image


    int hp;

    //control; AI or human
    char control;//0 human, otherwise AI
};


int main( void )
{
    struct OBJ objs[2];

    objs[1].animation = 1;
    objs[1].pho.h = 52;
    objs[1].pho.w = 25;
    objs[1].pho.tmp_pos.x = 190;
    objs[1].pho.tmp_pos.y = 40;
    objs[1].pho.gravity = 1;
    objs[1].hp = 10;

    printf("%d\n", objs[1].hp);//outputs 0???????

    return 0;
}
```

When compiled, linked, run, the output is as follows:

```
10
```

So the problem is in something you have not shown us.